# How to close all branches in

Tags: qooxdoo

I try to close all branches in a qx.ui.treevirtual.TreeVirtual tree

```
 this._tree.addListener( "dblclick", function( e )
 {
     for( var i = 0; i< this._tree.getDataModel().getRowCount(); i++ )
     {
        var child = this._tree.getDataModel().getNode( i );
        if( child.level == 1 && child.bOpened == true )
        {
           this._tree.nodeSetOpened( i, false );
        }
     }
}, this );
```

however it says nodeSetOpened is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodeSetOpened` is a method that is provided by the `qx.ui.treevirtual.MNode` mixin. Near the top of your application's main() method, add this code to include the mixin`:

`// We want to use some of the high-level node operation convenience
      // methods rather than manually digging into the TreeVirtual helper
      // classes.  Include the mixin that provides them.
      qx.Class.include(qx.ui.treevirtual.TreeVirtual,
                       qx.ui.treevirtual.MNode);`

Comment: worked perfectly for me. Thank you. I did a 

    this._tree.nodeSetOpened( child, false );